# "stack level too deep" error in show#controller for nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I get an

> SystemStackError in Admin::ChecklistsController#show
>
> stack level too deep

The Controller Action:

```
# GET /admin/checklists/1
# GET /admin/checklists/1.json
def show
  @admin_checklist = Admin::Checklist.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html #show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @admin_checklist }
  end
end
```

And the models

```
class Admin::Checklist < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :usable, :categories_attributes
  has_many :categories, :dependent => :destroy
  validates_presence_of :name,:description

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories, :allow_destroy => true

end

class Admin::Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :export_head, :export_position, :export_text, :frontend_head, :frontend_position, :frontend_text
  belongs_to :checklist
  validates_presence_of :frontend_head, :frontend_text

end
```

I already played around a bit with the attributes_accessible. If I replace :categories_attributes by :categories

Then I loose the endless loop error, but as expected, I can't mass-assign any category attributes anymore

Anyone got an idea how i can fix both errors.

**EDIT:**

> Started GET "/admin/checklists/4" for 192.168.4.191 at 2012-12-12
>   10:12:41 +0100 Processing by Admin::ChecklistsController#show as HTML 
>   Parameters: {"id"=>"4"}   Admin::Checklist Load (0.2ms)  SELECT
>   "admin_checklists".* FROM "admin_checkli
>   sts" WHERE "admin_checklists"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "4"]]   CACHE
>   (0.0ms)   SELECT "admin_checklists".* FROM "admin_checklists" WHERE
>   "admi
>   n_checklists"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "4"]] Completed 500 Internal
>   Server Error in 240ms
>
> SystemStackError (stack level too deep):   actionpack (3.2.9)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70
>
> Rendered
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middlew 
>   are/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.5ms)   Rendered
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middlew 
>   are/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.3ms)   Rendered
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middlew 
>   are/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (10.7ms)

I get this SQL-Staement about 100 times for each Page request. This seems to be some bug in active record or miss-usage by me of active record for nested models .....

**Edit2:**

> irb(main):001:0> Admin::Checklist.find('4')   Admin::Checklist Load
>   (0.2ms)  SELECT "admin_checklists".* FROM "admin_checkli
>   sts" WHERE "admin_checklists"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "4"]]
>   => #
>   BrummliBrummliBrummliBrummliBrummliBrummliBr...", usable: false,
>   created_at: "20                                12-12-11 13:43:23",
>   updated_at: "2012-12-11 13:43:23">

Comment: Ged rid of ` show.html.erb` [Docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to)

Comment: Thats not the problem, I know that wrong, the error is triggered by the find action. I edited top post.

Comment: Trying to track down something similar, what version of rails were you on for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny fact it now works and I'm not quite sure what really fixed it, because i changed nothing. I just came back from my break. Did the find on the console. Checked it in the template again and i got a different error message belonging to a malformed loop, because i had removed it again, which i fixed by pasting the removed part in again.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @admin_checklist.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Description:</b>
  <%= @admin_checklist.description %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Usable:</b>
  <%= @admin_checklist.usable %>
</p>

<p>
    <ul>
        <% @admin_checklist.categories.each do |category|%>
            <li>
                <h3><%= category.frontend_head %></h3>
                <p><%= category.frontend_text %></p>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</p>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_checklist_path(@admin_checklist) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', admin_checklists_path %>
```

I'm sorry I can't provide an answer why this happened.